# SQL syntax error when inserting new row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Below is my code for when the user clicks *Apply Balance.* This works for the first part and the user's balance updates just fine but when I try and execute the second statement a SQL syntax errors appears. What may be causing the problem?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (cal == true) {
                try {
                int balchange = updatebal;
                String username = (String) userPicker.getSelectedItem();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );  
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table_1 SET user_bal='"+balchange+"' WHERE user_name='"+username+"'");
                pst.execute();


                String sign = "£";
                String PayName = textField_1.getText();
                PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payment_info (payment_name, payment_amount, payment_date, username)"+" VALUES ('"+PayName+"', '"+sign+balchange+"', '"+Date+"', '"+username+"'");
                pst2.execute();
                cal = false;
                } 
                catch (Exception e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please use the Calculator First!");
            }
        }
```

Below is the stack trace I get when I run this.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
at AdminPanelMain$7.mouseClicked(AdminPanelMain.java:444)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: May be you can print out the SQL statements before you execute them -- that way any syntax problems will be more visible. Consider using `PreparedStatement` to supply parameters -- as it is now your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You should look at what query it actually generated.  This is most likely due to your string-concatenation of a SQL query.  You should use prepared statements for *all* queries that accept parameters.  Not only do they prevent situations like this, but they also safeguard your code from SQL Injection.  Imagine what would happen if my balance change was `0' --` Or even better, `10000000' --` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second query is missing closing bracket in `Values` clause.

Instead of directly appending parameters in the query use parameterized queries.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (cal == true) {
        try {
        int balchange = updatebal;
        String username = (String) userPicker.getSelectedItem();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );  
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table_1 SET user_bal=? WHERE user_name=?");

        pst.setInt(1, balchange);
        pst.setString(2, username);

        pst.execute();

        String sign = "£";
        String PayName = textField_1.getText();
        PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payment_info (payment_name, payment_amount, payment_date, username)"
        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        pst2.setString(1, PayName);
        pst2.setString(2, sign + balchange);
        pst2.setString(3, "Date");//if it's date column use ps2.setDate(3, new Date());
        pst2.setString(4, username);

        pst2.execute();
        cal = false;
        } 
        catch (Exception e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please use the Calculator First!");
    }
}
```

That will look much cleaner and will be easier to write. Most of all it will save you from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Here's Oracle Docs for parameterized queries https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thanks this got it working perfectly, Love the way you lay things out will start using this kind of layout more.

Answer (score 2):

Look at here:

```
PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payment_info (payment_name, payment_amount, payment_date, username)"+" VALUES ('"+PayName+"', '"+sign+balchange+"', '"+Date+"', '"+username+"'")
```

It seems like you lack of right bracket in your sql statement which should be `VALUES()` not `VALUES(`.

By the way, there are several ORM systems, such as `mybatis` or `hibernate`, why not choose one? They are not only can help you reduce work also makes it easy to access your database.

Comment: This still causes the SQL Syntax error to appear. Could the problem be linked to me not creating a ID for the Unique ID or should it not matter?

Comment: Please debug it and post the real sql statement, it shoud be easy to know what is going wrong.

Comment: The Post above managed to fix my problem but thanks for the help. Only just started using stackoverflow so its all new to me.